# Can't reorder data frame columns by matching column names given in another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to re-order the variables of my data frame using the contents of a variable in another data frame but it's not working and I don't know why.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
# Starting point 
df_main <- data.frame(coat=c(1:5),hanger=c(1:5),book=c(1:5),
                      bottle=c(1:5),wall=c(1:5))
df_order <- data.frame(order_var=c("wall","book","hanger","coat","bottle"),
                       number_var=c(1:5))

# Goal
df_goal <-  data.frame(wall=c(1:5),book=c(1:5),hanger=c(1:5),
                       coat=c(1:5),bottle=c(1:5))

# Attempt
df_attempt <- df_main[df_order$order_var]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you `df_order`, put `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `data.frame` call.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have the order as a factor, if you change it to a character it will work:

```
df_goal <- df_main[as.character(df_order$order_var)]
```